# Jsp call redirect management

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

How to check if return call is from same browser/tab where it was forwarded.
If A calls B and then need to check if return call to A is from B not the other browser or tab i.e. C or D

Comment: Do you mean redirect or forward? There is a difference. Redirect: First request is answered with redirct URL so the browser initiates a second request with the new URL. Forward: Server forwards internally while processing the request. For the browser this is only one request.

Comment: Say it as redirect; there are multiple i.e B,C,D urls. Call is made to B URL from A URL then user completes work on B application then user will have redirect button which will return to A url. So on A application, i want to validate that user/ request is from B application not the C or D url.

Comment: Do you have something like Paypal in mind? The user is on an ecommerce site. At the checkout page the browser is redirected to the Paypal site. After authorization the browser is redirected back to the checkout page.

Comment: Yes, similar flow